# How to detect a left/right click event target in ListView in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Here I got a ListView. I need to take different operations when the user left/right click on an item or the white space without any items. 
So how to know the click event is happening on an item or white space ? Where should I handle it in the ListView's events ?

Comment: Handle them at `ListViewItem` level or the `ItemTemplate` level.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use ListView ItemClick event to get whether is a right or left button Click.

But you can AddHandle in the ListViewItem.

If you have a Grid in ListViewItem that you can add handle to get the mouse down.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind AvaloniaCol}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListViewBase_OnItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Background="#FFFFFF" PointerPressed="UIElement_OnPointerPressed">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

You can write the UIElement_OnPointerPressed in cs.

```
    private void UIElement_OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            var p = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender);
            if (p.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
            {

            }
            else if (p.Properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

You can use `var p = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender);` and p.Properties to get whether is left or right button click.

See http://lindexi.oschina.io/lindexi//post/win10-uwp-%E8%8E%B7%E5%8F%96%E6%8C%89%E9%92%AE%E9%BC%A0%E6%A0%87%E5%B7%A6%E9%94%AE%E6%8C%89%E4%B8%8B/

Comment: If you use the button that can AddHandler in the code but cant AddHandler in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [UIElement.ContextRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.contextrequested) event, which will work for mouse and touch.